# iOS layout - different sized elements for different devices

Tags: xcode, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a complex UI design that is tight for space, and consequently have been handed two designs, one for iPhone 5 5s and SE devices, and another for the remaining devices.

The designs are identical except for differing widths and heights on a large number of elements.

What options are available to me to make these adjustments?

Initially I was under the impression that using vary for traits would be possible, but as all the devices have compact widths this is not possible. Alternatively I could manipulate the constraints on the fly depending on screen width. This is do-able but considering the number of changes to be made it would be messy and not maintainable.

Are there any other options available to me? One possibility is to push back on the designs.

Comment: Show us how's your ui look like in which you want help.

Comment: @GovindKumawat Sorry, this is not possible as the product is in development.

Comment: you can post a UI similar to that it will make more sense in explaining.